# ASP.NET Disable page formatting when not full screen

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application on VS2005 using C#.

Whenever my webpage does not open up in full screen, the icons and labels will automatically adjust to fit the width of the windows, making the buttons and icons disoriented.

Is there any way to disable this or enable the format to be fixed regardless if the windows is full screen or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be hard to do. You could use a function in javascript to chceck if browser is in full screen. Then you woud have to do this in intervals to make sure that this is  or is not true.

```
if (screen.width == window.innerWidth && screen.height == window.innerHeight) {
// web browser full screen
}
```

Based on that you could make another screen CSS template that you could apply based on that condition. Then you could make your site apply another layout.

Another approach I would reccoment is to make your CSS layout in a way that you would be satisfied with it with any browser size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to set `width` (which will be fixed) or `min-width` (layout will not shrink to less). `min-width` is not supported on older versions of IE.

In both cases if the browser window is smaller (or the available space – if something like history is opened down the side) than this then horizontal scrolling will be alloed.

However consider that many users have very wide screens these days, far too wide for comfortable reading if a browser is maximised.